# How can you make a div clickable by a link in the div without changing HTML

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

I'm trying to make a div that contains text and a link but the div should be clickable.

I know that I can do:

```
<a href="#link">
  <div>
    <p> some text</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn_link">my link</a>
  </div>
</a>
```

but in my case, I need to put a link in the div and when I click on the div I should be redirected to the link in the `a` tag with this class "btn_link", and the `a` tag should not be visible

I have tried to do this :

```
<div class="my_div">
  <p> some text</p>
  <a href="#link" class="btn_link"></a>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.btn_link a {
  background: none !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```

I don't know how to make the button cover the whole div to make it clickable.

NB: I can't change the HTML structure, it's important to do it with CSS.

Could someone tell me what CSS property I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely position the link

```css
.btn_link {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.my_div {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_div">
  <p> some text</p>
  <a href="#link" class="btn_link"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some additional Javascript code.

```js
// set an event listener to the div
document
  .querySelector(".link_div")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
    // calculate the position of the element immediately
    // after .btn_link. We cannot get the offsetTop for .btn_link because it is hidden (display:none) so the Y position of immediate next element should be as good as itself.
    posY = document.querySelector(".btn_link").nextElementSibling.offsetTop
    window.scrollTo(0, posY)
  });
```

```css
.btn_link {
  display: none
}

.spacer {
  padding-bottom: 120vh;
  background: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<div class="link_div">
  <p>some text</p>
  <p class="spacer">some space to show how scroll is working .... </p>
  <a href="#link" class="btn_link"></a>
  <p>some text after the link. The link above is hidden</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here it is with only HTML and CSS:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    
<!--The <div>, like you wanted-->
<div>
<!--This  will be the link in the background-->
<a class="hidden-link" href="example.com">
<!--Your text (Wich is a hidden link)-->
<p>Some Text</p>
<!--Your official link-->
<a href="example.com">My Link</a>   
</a>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.hidden-link{
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: black;
}
```

Output:

[Output-Click me to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CgcB.png)

Both links go to "example.com" except for one is hidden as text, and the other is plainly a link.

Comment: The OP cannot change the HTML